# Exponential matrix estimate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

$B=C^{-1}AC=\left[ 
        \begin{array}{cc}
         P & 0\\ 
         0 & Q
         \end{array}
      \right]$
consider the system y'=By+G(y).

Let $U(t)=\left[ 
        \begin{array}{cc}
         e^{Pt} & 0\\ 
         0 & 0
         \end{array}
      \right] $ and $V(t)=\left[ 
        \begin{array}{cc}
         0 & 0\\ 
         0 & e^{Qt}
         \end{array}
      \right] $ where $P$ is $k\times k$ has eigenvalues with negative real part and $Q$ is $(n-k) \times (n-k)$ has eigenvalues with positive real part. For $\alpha>0$ sufficiently small that for $j=1,..,k$ we choose $Re(\lambda_{j})<-\alpha<0$. We have $e^{Bt}=U(t)+V(t)$

Why in the proof it was written that for $K>0$ and $\delta <0$ we have
$$
||U(t)||\le Ke^{-(\alpha+\delta)t} \text{ for all $t\ge 0$}
$$
 and
$$
||V(t)||\le Ke^{\delta t} \text{ for all $t\le 0$}
$$

Comment: You should give more context.

Comment: Still the context is missing: for instance, does your last sentence mean "there exist $K>0$ and $\delta\,{\color{red}<}\,0$ such that $\lVert V(t)\rVert\le Ke^{\delta t}$ for all $t\,{\color{red}\le}\,0$"? If so, this follows in a straightforward way from the standard estimates of the exponential matrix, independent of the signs of the real parts of its eigenvalues. Please take more care in formulating your question, otherwise it can be downvoted and eventually closed.